# Как склонять мужчину-весы?

Tags: падежи

Им.мужчина-весы

Р.мужчины-весов

Д.мужчине-весам

В.мужчину-весы

Т.мужчиной-весами

П.мужчине-весах

Правильно? Представляется. что в тексте некоторые формулировки звучат неуклюже. Например: "вы встретитесь с мужчиной-весами". Кажется, это странно звучит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласна с Вами, выглядит странно, я обычно не сокращаю, так и говорю:"Вы встретитесь с мужчиной, рождённым под знаком Весы" или "с мужчиной знака Весы". Названия знаков зодиака принято писать с большой буквы без дефиса.

Грамота на похожий вопрос ответила так:

> Как правильно написать: выбрать подарок мужчине-Весам или
>   мужчине-Весы?
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
>
> **Возможно**: **мужчине  Весам**. Но лучше избегать такого словоупотребления.
>   http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5&start=60